# CSS styling not working in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, styles, postageapp

I have a variable

```
 $mail_body = array(
    'text/html' => 
    '<style> .fb_term { font-weight:bold;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;    
}</style>' );
```

and inside my code I do this

```
$mail_body['text/html'] .= $a;
$a ='How <span class="fb_term" >Assist</span> me Please <span class="fb_term" >Grad</span>'
```

I get the mail but the styling is not done,

What could be the problem?

Comment: Check the source of the mail, if the stylesheet it still there.

Comment: @NoLifeKing How I can see the css? I check the show orignal in gmail and it is there

Comment: If you change your span to a div, does it work then?

Comment: If you want to style an e-mail i think that is better to use inline styles instead of using classes (i think that this is not going to work on all mail readers). So, you could do <span style="font-weigth:bold;">Grad</span> for example.

Comment: Can you provide the full HTML that you generate?

Comment: @NoLifeKing it doesnt work with div too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be e-mail HTML, which is notoriously difficult to style. Don't use classes, use inline styles for every bit of CSS.

```
How <span style="font-weight:bold; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;" >Assist</span> me Please <span style="font-weight:bold; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;" >Grad</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

What mail browser did you use to test output (Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo or Outlook)? Are you sure they all support `style` tags? Are you sure they all support the css directives you used for your elements.

I suggest you take a look at [this site](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), it has some test data on css directives and mail browsers. And use directives in-line not in a `style` tag. For example:

```
<div style="background-color:black;color:white"></div>
```

Also make sure you mark the correct mail header `Content-Type` as `text/html`. If it is just `text`, it wont be rendered correctly.